# How to check if grep recursive returns something?

Tags: bash

I went to check if grep recursive (`grep -r`) returning something or not, so I tried this:

```
  v5='blabla'
  if grep -rq "$v5" "$1"; then

   echo "word found Ok : $5"

   else 

   echo "not found"

   fi
```

`$1` is a parameter.
When I put `grep -q "$v5" "name_Of_File"` it works:
I have this output: `word found Ok`, but for me I want to search in all directories and sub-directories.

Comment: You could use `/` or `.` or `$PWD` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `grep -rq "$v5" "$1"` with `$1` being a directory. Your code should work as expected. No problem.

**EDIT:**

I just tried your script and only replaced `$5`/`$v5` with `$1` and changed `$1` to `$2` to have two parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -rq "$1" "$2"; then
        echo "word found Ok : $1"
else
        echo "not found"
fi
```

Save the script as `rgrep.sh` and run `chmod +x rgrep.sh`.
To test it, create a test file and run the script (here with output):

```
$ echo blablah > /tmp/blah
$ ./rgrep.sh "blabla" /tmp
word found Ok : blabla
$ ./rgrep.sh "blah" /tmp
word found Ok : blah
$ ./rgrep.sh "blapp" /tmp
not found
```

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work, but when i replace $1 (directory) by a file, and i remove -r  it works